# ios add float property to UIButton or derive

Tags: iphone, ios, properties, uibutton

I need to store into a `UIButton` the latitude and longitude, so 2 floats..
how can I do this??
I need this to use the coordinates in the pins over the map: 
the problem is that the button (actually with the arrow on the right (>) is a `UIButton` and the event that I use to catch the click have only `(id)sender` as parameter, and if I have more than one pin is not possible...

thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you just use annotaion?Why looking for a button search "Map callout ios"

Comment: i use annotation but after in the button click?

Comment: where are you placing the button? on the map?and what is the purpose of button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: Don't use a UIButton, use a subclass of a UIButton like so:

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (readwrite) float latitude;
@property (readwrite) float longitude;

@end

@implementation

@end
```

If you're creating these buttons in a XIB file, simply select the button, and change its custom class from UIButton to MyButton and the XIB loading mechanism will take care of the rest of the business for you.

Note: If you're using this within an MKAnnotationView, you're probably better off associating the actual annotation or annotation's CLLocation rather than storing the individual co-ordinates.

Comment: thanks @david-doyle.. I need this 'cause I need to do a thing like this: http://cl.ly/image/0u3r3w3J2F2T/Image%202012.08.20%207:59:05%20PM.png where I need to get directions clicking on the car

Comment: What does it crash with? Got a crash log?

Comment: -[UIButton setLongitude:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18785ef0
2013-06-01 14:44:02.486 Salento[1236:1d903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setLongitude:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18785ef0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2a6e012 0x20b8e7e 0x2af94bd 0x2a5dbbc 0x2a5d94e 0x2f3f9 0xf104c4 0xf227e9 0xf23b9f 0xf239da 0xf23df3 0xf0f764 0xf0f794 0xf11fad 0x2e693 0x10e3753 0x10e3b2f 0x10e3d54 0x10f7bd3 0x127e351 0x127e629 0x127e698 0x103e3b6 0x103e554 0xc737d8 0x2288014 0x22787d5 0x2a14af5 0x2a13f44 0x2a13e1b

Comment: Well, there's the issue. You're still using a UIButton somewhere. Find where its created, and change it to the subclass.